# How do I make an entry field optional?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have made an entry field required somehow but I'm not sure how. When editing a tag, the tag owner entry field should be able to be empty.
[image]

I have set "allow nulls" in the database table:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix it? To be clear, I want the above form to be submitted without requiring a value for tag_owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix by editing the properties of the .dbml file in the designer view rather than editing in the database explorer. I don't know why this worked, but it did so I am happy.

Answer (score -1):

Check your source for a requiredfield tag or click the tag_owner textbox and remove extenders